# Agregar diferentes valores a datos dentro de una listas

Tags: c#

tengo una lista en c# que añade diferentes tipos de empleados, mí duda seria como dependiendo del id puedo agregar valores como turnos de trabajos o vehículos asignados por el id de cargo, por ejemplo: id 2 tiene turno vespertino o id 3 se le fue asignado un vehículo, apreciaría mucho su ayuda, saludos

```
class Ingresarempl
{
    
    List<Empleados> empleado = new List<Empleados>();

    internal void agregar()
    {


        while (true)
        {



            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");                                            
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Rut:\nNombre:");
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el id del cargo");
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del cargo");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");


            empleado.Add(new Empleados()
            {
                
                rut = Console.ReadLine(),
                nombre = Console.ReadLine(),
                id=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()),
                nombrec=Console.ReadLine()
            });;
            
            break;

            
        }    
        
    }
    internal void mostrar()
    {
        foreach (Empleados emo in empleado)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(emo);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir, podrías dar más detalles, pq no pones lo que dice tu ejercicio

Comment: 2. Empleados
 Personas que trabajan en el minimarket
 Los empleados se dividen en:
Empleados de Administración
Empleados de producción
Puede tener turnos
Empleados de logística
Puede tener asignado un vehículo

Comment: Sigo sin entenderte, seria buena que editaras tu pregunta y dieras más detalles

Comment: Con un poco más de detalle podría intentar resolverlo, pero el tema de los id si es 11 o es 2 no lo entiendo